# c remove the first character of an array

Tags: c

I have a string:

```
str1 = "abcabcabc";
```

How can I remove the first character? I would like the end result to be:

```
str1 = "bcabcabc";
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have a character pointer to a string like:

```
char *s = "This is my string";
```

then you can just do `s++`.

If you have a character *array,* your best bet may be to have a pointer to that array as well:

```
char s[] = "This is my string";
char *ps = s;
```

then you can do `ps++` and make sure you use `ps` rather than `s`.

If you don't want to have a separate pointer to your array then you can use `memmove` to copy the data:

```
memmove (s, s+1, strlen (s+1) + 1); // or just strlen (s)
```

though none of those will work for an initially empty string so you'll have to check that first. Also keep in mind it's not advisable to attempt modifying string *literals* in this way (or *any* way, really) since it's undefined as to whether that's allowed.

Another solution is to simply code up a loop:

```
for (char *ps = s; *ps != '\0'; ps++)
    *ps = *(ps+1);
*ps = '\0';
```

This will work for all strings, empty or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to you, half of my nerves have been ripped out. :)

Comment: Just one comment.  Keep the original pointer if the space for the string is malloc'ed, otherwise there won't be a way to free that space.  If the space was hard-coded, then of course no problem.  +1 on the recursive beast.  :-)

Comment: Not exactly sure at the moment... but shouldn't `memmove (s, s+1, strlen (s+1));` be `memmove (s, s+1, strlen (s-1));`?

Comment: @mozzbozz, no, you may be thinking of `strlen (s) - 1` which would be correct, equivalent to `strlen (s + 1)` except for the degenerate case where `s[0] == 0`.  The expression `strlen (s - 1)` is not the same thing.

Comment: @mozzbozz: however, your comment led me to a flaw where I didn't copy the final NUL, so thanks for that, I've fixed it.

Comment: Ahh yes. That's exactly what I've read: `stlen(s) + 1` - normally, I don't use whitespaces between the function names and the paramters list - that might have irritated me. You're totally right :) C pointer etc. can be handy but when it comes to string handling, it's freaking error prone :[]

Answer (score 7):

**Pointer tricks (zero-cost):**

```
char* s = "abcd";
char* substr = s + 1;
// substr == "bcd"
```

Or:

```
char s[] = "abcd";
char* substr = s + 1;
// substr == "bcd"
```

---

**In-place via [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/):**

```
char s[] = "abcd";
char* substr = s + 1;
memmove(s, substr, strlen(substr) + 1);
// s == "bcd"
```

Notice that we must use `char[]` rather than `char*`, which would refer to read-only memory, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704433/365102). Furthermore, one should not use `strcpy` in-place because the src and dest must not overlap for `strcpy`.

---

**Into a new string via [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/):**

```
char* src = "abcd";
char* substr = src + 1;
char dest[strlen(substr) + 1];
strcpy(dest, substr);
// dest == "bcd"
```

---

**Into a new string via C++'s [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):**

```
std::string src = "abcd";
std::string dest = src.substr(1);
// dest == "bcd"
```

---

**Into a new string via C++'s [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/):**

```
std::string src = "abcd";
std::string dest;
std::copy(src.begin() + 1, src.end(), std::back_inserter(dest));
// dest == "bcd"
```

---

There's a couple dozen other ways (particularly when including C++), but I'll stop here. :)

Comment: This suffers from three flaws (one per section). (1) You cannot increment a character _array,_ only a pointer. (2) This one creates a _new_ string, though that's probably fixable by copying back to the original afterwards. (3) Your C++ solution is probably right (I can't comment on that) but it's hardly useful for a C question :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo (1) I fixed it, then unfixed it because I couldn't remember why I fixed it. :) (2) Does it look OK now? (3) Yeah, I like C++. :)

Comment: that whole 3-line `if` bit could be replaced with `strcpy(str2, &(str1[1]));`, no `pstr1` required, and the `sizeof` (in the `if`) should probably be `strlen`.

Comment: I really like the strcpy method, is there a way to use that to remove not only the first letter but also the last letter?

Comment: @Cheetaiean You can use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/).

Answer (score 1):

If you really meant to say

```
char str1 [] = "abcabcabc";
```

Then the easiest thing is

```
str1 = &str1[1];
```

If you want to modify the actual data, then you have to just move everything up one position. You can use a loop for that or `memmove()`. A recursive function is overkill.

If you really meant C++ and you're using the string object then you can use

```
str1 = str1.substr(1);
```

Comment: The problem is not in the decaying (which _does_ happen), the problem is in trying to asign to a non-pointer.

Comment: It works if the str1 is declared as `char* str1`. You're right, if you declare `char str1[]` then it won't work. But it's not clear what the OP is using.

Comment: @Adam What happens if &str1 is passed to a function that expects `char **` and is incremented there? Does it cause a crash when `str1` goes out of scope?

Comment: @dashesy if str1 is declared as `char* str1` then you can't pass it to a function that accepts a `char **` anyway. A crash happens (hopefully) when you access memory that has been freed. That's unrelated to the above. If `str1` goes out of scope then any statement involving `str1` is a compiler error.

Comment: @Adam- I meant passing &str1 when `char str1[]="abcabcabc";`

Comment: @dashesy that's a pointer to a pointer, so if you increment it you'll be incrementing by `sizeof(char*)` (i.e. 4 or 8) instead of `sizeof(char)` (i.e. 1). In other words, you're implying to the compiler that you have an array of pointers to strings, not an array of characters. Note that `&str1` is not the same as `str1`, so you'll get different results anyway. But you could still do `(*arg)++` if `arg` is that `char**` argument

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
int index = 0; //index to cull
memmove( &word[ index ] , &word[ index +1], strlen( word ) - index) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as i know if you are worried about memory allocation you have to copy (str1+1) into a new string that you personally allocate memory for, then free the first pointer.
The really simple way to do it would be to just increment str1 with str1++; That would make it point one character farther than it used to and give you the desired result with just a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main(){
   char a[10];
   int i;
   gets(a);

   for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      a[i] = a[i + 1];
   }

   printf("\n");
   puts(a);
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char a[15] = "!Hello world!";
  sprintf(a,"%s",a+1);
  printf("%s",a);
}
```

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behaviour. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf): *The C standard and POSIX specify that the behavior of sprintf and its variants is undefined when an argument overlaps with the destination buffer.*