# Remove First two Characters from a Char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm having trouble removing the first two characters from my char array.

```
 input[MAXSIZE] = "./hello";

 for(int i = 2; i < MAXSIZE; i+=2)
 {
    strcpy(input[i-2],input[i]);
 }
```

and I'm getting the following errors:

```
 invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
 initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
 initializing argument 2 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
```

I know that this is a very basic problem but im fairly new to this. 
Also if there is an easier way to get around this problem feel free to educate me.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `std::string`?

Comment: you also may simply use a pointer to the third character (char* modified_input= &input[2]) as a new "array" without moving or copying characters at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy` copies null terminated char arrays, not characters.

What you want is:

```
input[i-2] = input[i];
```

Also, why don't you increment `i` with `1` but with `2`?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `strcpy` is not meant to be used like that and you can achieve the desired effect with

```
// loop step changed to 1; i += 2 is a mistake
for(int i = 2; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
{
    input[i-2] = input[i];
}
```

However, you can also simply use [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/):

```
memmove(input, input + 2, (MAXSIZE - 2) / sizeof(input[0]));
```

If `input` is guaranteed to be an array of `char` you can also remove the `/ sizeof(input[0])` part.

And of course **even better** would be to do it the standard library way, using [`std::copy_backward`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_backward/) (necessary because the source and destination ranges overlap):

```
#include <algorithm>
std::copy_backward(input + 2, input + MAXSIZE, input + MAXSIZE - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution you can simply use a pointer to char to "skip" the first two characters in the array:

```
char input[MAXSIZE] = {0};
snprintf_s<MAXSIZE>(input, _TRUNCATE, "./hello" ); //MSVC only
char* noDotSlash = input + 2;
cout << noDotSlash << endl; //should print just hello.
```

Comment: very elegant. i like it!

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` has to be used on char array not characters!!

Also look into this Que [c remove the first character of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711490/c-remove-the-first-character-of-an-array)