# How to remove a single character from the beginning of a character array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char a[15] = "!Hello world!";
    a[0] = '';
    printf_s("%s",a);
    getch();
}
```

I want to remove only one **!** which is in the beginning but using `a[0]='';` gives error and `a[0]=0;` works as `'\0'`. The output I want is `Hello world!`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [c remove the first character of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711490/c-remove-the-first-character-of-an-array). TL;DR: you can't do it directly, but there are workarounds using pointers.

Comment: try `printf("%s", a + 1);`

Comment: @tstanisl But I want to save that result to a variable.

Comment: so try `char *b = a + 1;`

Comment: Try [`memmove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memmove-wmemmove?view=msvc-170).